# Facing difficulty in interpreting the meaning of passage

Tags: comprehension, reading

"The main issues of interpretation arising from the work of professionally trained anthropologists are that **they are late in colonial/post-colonial  trajectories**,  because  professional  training  shapes  their  interpretations.  **However,  within field of interest and training, their works are most thorough and systematic.** "

Does this passage mean that anthropologist's (i.e. those who study the origin, development, and behavior of humans) work and their thinking have issues that they are old, and belong to colonial era ? Is their work not up to date because of their professional curriculum, however their study is thorough(that is dense) and systematic(perfectly designed curriculum covering from basics to advanced) ?

I am not a native English speaker so please help me to simplify the meaning

Comment: Conclusions anthropologists draw tend to be relative to their training, which based on the current understanding of the field (which is "late in colonial/post-colonial trajectories"). It's a relativist argument - you can't objectively assert something because your current perspective and the context you are looking at it from might distort it. It's hard to assert colonialism living in the postcolonial era.

Comment: The cited text has been copied into any number of TEFL tests - all of which slavishly replicate the syntax error in the final sentence (caused by omission of the highlighted word in *...within **their** field of interest...)*  The fact that people creating those TEFL contexts apparently don't notice that should tell you something about the quality of the test selectors, if not the text itself. Personally, I don't think much of the text - it looks like it's primarily intended to show how clever the writer is, rather than to actually ***communicate*** something.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko , sorry I did not quite get your explanation completely, what did you mean by relativist argument ? Is it that what they are taught in their training can't be used   in the post colonial era, is their curriculum is outdated ? how is the distortion taking place? sorry to ask but if you could write an answer that would be very good

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes you are correct about the error :), now it sounds right , but can you still explain me know if I understood what the writer wanted to write in there.

Comment: Besides the missing "their", the quote is otherwise modified from what Ian Keen, the writer wrote, which can be seen here: https://tinyurl.com/2s378v9f

Comment: @Fin27 Please see [Relativism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativism#Anthropological_versus_philosophical_relativism) (particularly the section about anthropological relativism). I think he meant their works are accurate from the perspective of the observer but might have flaws from the perspective of the subject

Comment: I think very few readers will actually understand exactly what the cited text means (I certainly don't! :) But my guess is the writer's primary intention is to take a pop at what he considers to be the "old guard" of *professionally trained anthropologists*, because he doesn't think their attitudes are sufficiently "post colonial" when they stray into expressing or implying opinions outside of their highly specialised areas of study. Basically, that we shouldn't use our knowledge of the past to shape *current* sociological opinions, because of all the unwanted colonial / imperial baggage.

Comment: (As a general principle, I don't think anthropologists should concern themselves too much with concepts like "colonialism" anyway, because that's essentially *politics*. So it's reassuring to see that the Wikipedia page for [**Anthropologist**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropologist) doesn't include a single instance of the characters **colon**.)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko who are Conclusions anthropologists ? and what did you mean by raw tend to be relative to their training, which based on the current understanding of the field, I am not able to understand it, please could you rephrase it in simpler language, also how is word relativism coming in here, how did you get to know its talking about relativism ?

Comment: @FumbleFingers so you mean to say their thinking is old fashioned ? like kind of biased to pre colonial era, and it is not should not be used to assess current situation ? but then why is author saying their work are thorough and systematic ?

Comment: I asked one of a retired English professor and he told me that the meaning of this paragraph is that their professional training biases their thinking to something (which he was not sure of) , and on the other hand the later part of sentence tells us that the study is thorough and systematic - which indicates unbiasedness, so it is a paradox ? is this explanation correct ?

Comment: @Fin27 *[The] conclusions [which/that] **anthropologists draw** tend...*

Comment: @Fin27: As I said before, I *don't* understand the text - if you're interested in the intended meaning, then I suppose you can keep digging. But I honestly don't think learning that meaning will teach you anything at all about *English*. Having said that, I'd guess the author acknowledges that the work of professionally trained anthropologists is "thorough and systematic" as a kind of "limited concession", since he *appears* to be primarily saying their work is flawed (because they don't share the writer's political opinions regarding "post-colonial society"). But I honestly don't know.

Comment: (I think it's a worthless text for TEFL purposes, and I don't really have anything to add to that.)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko can you rephrase this sentence again in little bit easy to understand English, I am not able to understand what you want to convey by saying **"draw tend to be relative to their training, which based on the current understanding of the field"**